# minimising function of multivariable constraints Matlab

Tags: matlab

How to minimise this function please teach me the code in `MATLAB`

```
Minimize Ra = (0.237 − 0.00175v + 8.693f − 0.00159z)
subjected to 124.53 ≤ v ≤ 167.03 
             0.025 ≤ f ≤ 0.083 
             6.2 ≤ z ≤ 14.8
```

Comment: Do you have the optimization toolbox? You can find out by typing `ver` on the MATLAB command prompt

Comment: I would too like to know how to do this in general, but in this case: It's a linear function, thus choosing the max/min values of `v`, `f` and `z` should suffice?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a (very degenerate) [linear program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).
Your unknown vector `x = [v; f; z]`, the objective coeff vector is `c = [-0.00175; 8.693; -0.00159]`.
In your particular case, you have no equality or inequality constraints, only lower and upper bounds `lb = [124.53; 0.025; 6.2]` and `ub = [167.03; 0.083; 14.8]` respectively.

You are trying to minimize

```
argmin c^T x
  s.t. lb <= x <= ub
```

Use [`linprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html)

```
x = linprog( c, [], [], [], [], lb, ub );
```

---

Note that the constant coefficient `0.237` is not participating in the optimization since it has no effect on the `argmin`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `fmincon`. Let's say `v = x(1)`, `f = x(2)`, and `z = x(3)` so that tehy are all in a vector. First you define a handle to your function as:

```
h = @(x)(0.237 - − 0.00175*x(1) + 8.693*x(2) − 0.00159*x(3))
```

You need to define your constraints in the form `A*x ≤ b`. In your example, we rewrite the constraints as both being less than some function:

```
v ≤ 167.03
-v ≤ -124.53 
f ≤ 0.083
-f ≤ -0.025 
z ≤ 14.8
-z ≤ -6.2
```

Now you can convert the above into matrix form `A*x ≤ b`:

```
A = [1,  0,  0;
     -1, 0,  0;
     0,  1,  0;
     0, -1,  0;
     0,  0,  1;
     0,  0, -1]
b = [167.03; -124.53; 0.083; -0.025; 14.8; -6.2]
```

Finally, you define an initial guess `x0` for your variable `x`, and optimize by calling `fmincon` as:

```
xOpt = fmincon(h, x0, A, b)
```

The initial guess can be any values that lie within your constraints, so `x0 = [167; 0.08; 14]` could work.

**EDIT**: You could also define your lower and upper bound vectors as `lb = [124.53; 0.025; 6.2]` and `ub = [167.03; 0.083; 14.8]` and call `fmincon` using:

```
xOpt = fmincon(h, x0, [], [], [], [], lb, ub)
```

Note: if you want to randomize your initial guess, you can use your `lb` and `ub` vectors to do so with `x0 = lb + (ub - lb)*rand()`.

This is a bit more powerful of a tool than you need for this problem, but hey, teach a man to fish.

Comment: When I use fmincon option this is the message I am getting this "Large-scale (trust region) method does not currently solve this type of problem,
 switching to medium-scale (line search)                  Optimization terminated: first-order optimality measure less
 than options.TolFun and maximum constraint violation is less
 than options.TolCon.
Active inequalities (to within options.TolCon = 1e-006):
  lower      upper     ineqlin   ineqnonlin
    2          1                      
               3                      

xOpt =

  167.0300
    0.0250
   14.8000

Comment: I got similar warnings. Basically it is saying to set some options differently, but it took care of it this time for you. The middle part is saying that it finished optimizing because the change in cost between two iterations is less than the prescribed tolerance, and the results are within the prescribed tolerance of the bounds you set. The last part is giving you a chart saying which constraints were hit while optimizing, which is good to know if you are searching for a global min (which probably won't be on one of your constraints).

Comment: Is there any other options to avoid

Comment: There are plenty of options. Check out the `fmincon` [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) and the `optimoptions` [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#f854721) for more info.

Comment: Yes i got the result from pattern search thamk you forvaluable suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's very simple:

```
>> Min_Ra = 0.237 − 0.00175*167.03 + 8.693*0.025 − 0.00159*14.8

ans = 
    0.1384905
```

:)

(just subtract the maximum permissible amounts while adding the minimum permissible amounts)

Comment: indeed, for this type of very degenerate linear program the solution is trivial.